# Read literal value of attribute for composite component from component tree

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a composite tag similiar to this :

```
<ui:decorate template="....">
   <ui:define name="...">
       <h:inputText value="#{value}"/>
   </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```

It is used in a page like

```
<ns:tag value="#{some.el.expression}"/>
```

It works fine as it is. Now I want to access the "some.el.expression" from java code. I need something similiar to *component.getValueExpression("value")* . 
It doesn't seems to work, if I cann it on the inputText node it give me "#{value}" which is not what I want. I am couldn't figure a way to access this value.
Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a similar question and solution for JSF 2.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518046/programmatically-get-expression-value-of-facelets-parameter-variable

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) to evaluate an EL expression programmatically.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Object value = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(
    context, "#{some.el.expression}", Object.class);
```

Where `Object.class` can be substituted by the real return type. Note that whatever it returns is dependent on the exact moment when you're evaluating the expression. It might not be in the EL scope yet, or it might already have been removed from the EL scope.