# Programatically Set Attribute with a Value Expression when component is within JSTL forEach loop

Tags: jsf, jstl, el

First time asking a question so please bear with me.
I have a pure Java custom component that extends UIInput (JSF 2.2, Mojarra) and I am using it like so:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <my:component item="#{item}" />
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to avoid unnecessarily specifying the 'value', 'valueChangeListener' and 'validator' attributes on the tag in the .xhtml file.

In my custom component I have overridden the setValueExpression method like so:

```
@Override
public void setValueExpression(String name, ValueExpression expression) {
    super.setValueExpression(name, expression);
    if ("item".equals(name)) {
        this.setValue(Components.createValueExpression("#{item.myValue}", MyValue.class));
        this.addValueChangeListener(new MethodExpressionValueChangeListener(Components.createVoidMethodExpression("#{item.myValueChanged}", ValueChangeEvent.class)));
        this.addValidator(new MethodExpressionValidator(Components.createVoidMethodExpression("#{item.validateMyValue}", FacesContext.class, UIComponent.class, Object.class)));
    }
}
```

I'm using OmniFaces there with its Components utility to reduce boilerplate code.

When it comes time to act on any of those three (validate on submit, for example) it results in:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'item' resolved to null
```

I am pretty sure I know why, I just don't know what to do about it.

I believe when it comes time for the three expressions I am trying to set programatically to be resolved it's trying to find a bean in some scope by the name, 'item' however that doesn't exist since 'item' was a point in time variable within a JSTL forEach loop.

I think there's a special deferred kind of expression that Weld is using for item itself (which I can kinda see when I debug that setValueExpression method) that is aware or otherwise has references to that point in time variable but I'm not doing the same thing when I set up those three expressions and therefore there's no handle to that later on when it comes time for them to be resolved.

I am sure there is a way to wire this together I'm just not seeing it.

Additionally, I know I could just put the three attributes on the tag in the .xhtml like this:

```
<my:component item="#{item}" value="#{item.myValue}" valueChangeListener="#{item.myValueChanged}" validator="#{item.validateMyValue}" />
```

Then they would get their special deferred expressions just like item itself does (and indeed everything works as expected this way) but I'd rather not - it's something I'd have to repeat a lot and it just seems like there should be a way to do what I am trying above.

Comment: The `this.setValue(...)` is definitely not correct. You need to use `this.setValueExpression("value", ...)` instead. For the other two I cannot tell off top of head if these are correct, I'd have to take a look myself first sometime if these still cause a failure after your adjustment.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look @BalusC, I did have setValueExpression in a previous attempt (of many, as these things usually go) and tried again just now however the behavior remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer.

What I kept seeing in the debugger kept nagging at me, I just wasn't sure how to wire up the same scenario manually, then I found a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518046/programmatically-get-expression-value-of-facelets-parameter-variable) with the following code snip at the very bottom:

```
VariableMapper varMapper = new DefaultVariableMapper();
varMapper.setVariable(mappingName, component.getValueExpression(mappedAttributeName));
return new ValueExpressionImpl(expression, null, null, varMapper, expectedType);
```

That was enough to point me in the right direction of re-using the incoming value expression for item itself in a VariableMapper instance which is in turn used to create the three value/method expressions so they each now have a handle & can resolve 'item' later on, when it comes time:

```
@Override
public void setValueExpression(String name, ValueExpression expression) {
    super.setValueExpression(name, expression);
    if ("item".equals(name)) {

        VariableMapper varMapper = new DefaultVariableMapper();
        varMapper.setVariable("item", expression);

        ValueExpressionImpl valExprImpl = new ValueExpressionImpl("#{item.myValue}", null, null, varMapper, MyValue.class);
        super.setValueExpression("value", valExprImpl);

        MethodExpressionImpl meExprImpl = new MethodExpressionImpl("#{item.myValueChanged}", null, null, varMapper, Void.class, new Class<?>[] {ValueChangeEvent.class});
        MethodExpressionValueChangeListener mevcl = new MethodExpressionValueChangeListener(meExprImpl);
        this.addValueChangeListener(mevcl);

        meExprImpl = new MethodExpressionImpl("#{item.validateMyValue}", null, null, varMapper, Void.class, new Class<?>[] {FacesContext.class, UIComponent.class, Object.class});
        MethodExpressionValidator mev = new MethodExpressionValidator(meExprImpl);
        this.addValidator(mev);

    }
}
```

That seems to have done the trick (and looks so simple now...).